# Memory issue in machine learning project tensorflow.keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, memory, memory-management

The problem occurs after the first batch of 150 training images is processed. The model begins processing the next training batch, prints 1-3 images from it (for debugging), and then the RAM usage spikes dramatically from 7GB to 36GB, causing the program to crash. The model never gets to the validation set.
some logs I encountered:
`Allocation of 5910240000 exceeds 10% of free system memory. This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_0' with dtype int32. TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT`
I assume the problem is in my data_generator. I edited it, but nothing helped. Do you have any ideas why is it happening?

#### My data_generator:

```
!pip install opencv-python
!pip install pydicom

import numpy as np
import pydicom
import cv2


def conditional_resize(img, img_id, target_height=3518, target_width=2800):
    # Get the original image dimensions
    original_height, original_width = img.shape[:2]

    # Initialize the output image as the input image
    output_img = img

    # Case 1: If the original image matches the target dimensions, leave it as it is
    if original_height == target_height and original_width == target_width:
        output_img = img

    else:
        # Case 2: If the original image is smaller than the target dimensions, pad it
        if original_height < target_height and original_width < target_width:
            pad_h = target_height - original_height
            pad_w = target_width - original_width
            output_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, 0, pad_h, 0, pad_w, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)

        # Case 3: If the original image is larger than the target dimensions, crop it
        elif original_height > target_height and original_width > target_width:
            crop_h = (original_height - target_height) // 2
            crop_w = (original_width - target_width) // 2
            output_img = img[crop_h:crop_h + target_height, crop_w:crop_w + target_width]

        # Case 4: If original image HEIGHT is larger than target AND WIDTH is smaller than target
        elif original_height > target_height and original_width < target_width:
            # Crop the height
            crop_h = (original_height - target_height) // 2
            cropped_img = img[crop_h:crop_h + target_height, :]

            # Pad the width
            pad_w = target_width - original_width
            output_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(cropped_img, 0, 0, 0, pad_w, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)

        # Case 5: If original image HEIGHT is smaller than target AND WIDTH is larger than target
        elif original_height < target_height and original_width > target_width:
            # Pad the height
            pad_h = target_height - original_height
            padded_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, 0, pad_h, 0, 0, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)

            # Crop the width
            crop_w = (original_width - target_width) // 2
            output_img = padded_img[:, crop_w:crop_w + target_width]

    print("\n IMAGE:", img_id, original_height, original_width, output_img.shape)
    return output_img

    mapping_dict_density = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3}
    mapping_dict_laterality = {'left': 0, 'right': 1}
    mapping_dict_view_position = {'CC': 0, 'MLO': 1}

    while True:
        # Select files (IDs) and labels for the batch
        batch_indices = np.random.choice(a=len(df), size=batch_size)
        batch_df = df.iloc[batch_indices]

        batch_size = 150  # The number of samples per batch
        height = 3518  # The height of your images
        width = 2800  # The width of your images
        num_features = 2  # Number of feature columns, here you have 'laterality' and 'view_position'

        # Initialize your arrays
        batch_images = np.zeros((batch_size, height, width), dtype=np.float32)  # Adjust dtype as needed
        batch_labels_birads = np.zeros((batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int)  # Assuming birads labels are integers
        batch_labels_density = np.zeros((batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int)  # Assuming density labels are integers
        batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, num_features), dtype=np.int)  # Assuming features are integers
        batch_weights_birads = np.zeros((batch_size,), dtype=np.float32)  # Assuming weights are float numbers
        batch_weights_density = np.zeros((batch_size,), dtype=np.float32)  # Assuming weights are float numbers


        for i, original_idx in enumerate(batch_indices):
            row = batch_df.iloc[i]

            img_id = row['image_id']
            study_id = row['study_id']
            img_path = f"/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/vindr-mammo-a-large-scale-benchmark-dataset-for-computer-aided-detection-and-diagnosis-in-full-field-digital-mammography-1.0.0/images/{study_id}/{img_id}.dicom"
            img = pydicom.dcmread(img_path).pixel_array


            img = conditional_resize(img, img_id)
            batch_images[i] = img
            batch_labels_birads[i, 0] = row['breast_birads'] - 1
            batch_labels_density[i, 0] = mapping_dict_density.get(row['breast_density'], -1)
            batch_features[i] = [mapping_dict_laterality.get(row['laterality'], -1),
                                 mapping_dict_view_position.get(row['view_position'], -1)]
            batch_weights_birads[i] = sample_weights_birads[original_idx]
            batch_weights_density[i] = sample_weights_density[original_idx]




        yield {'image_input': batch_images, 'feature_input': batch_features}, \
            {'birads_output': batch_labels_birads, 'density_output': batch_labels_density}, \
            {'birads_output': batch_weights_birads, 'density_output': batch_weights_density}
```

#### Model.fit

```
history = model.fit(
    my_data_generator(
        training_data,
        batch_size=150,
        # birads_output =
        sample_weights_birads=sample_weights_birads_train,
        sample_weights_density=sample_weights_density_train,
    ),
    # steps_per_epoch=len(training_data) // 150,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=my_data_generator(
        validation_data,
        batch_size=32,
        sample_weights_birads=sample_weights_birads_val,
        sample_weights_density=sample_weights_density_val,
    ),
    # validation_steps=len(validation_data) // 32,
    callbacks=[checkpoint]
)
```

I've changed for each loop, arrays to np.arrays, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You are using images with very large size of 3518x2800 with batch size of 150. If I am not mistake it's about 4.1Gb (16.4Gb if dtype=np.float32) of memory only for images in one batch.
After the `# Initialize your arrays` section you allocate even more memory for intermediate arrays.

I believe you should consider using smaller images and/or smaller batch size to fix your issue.

Comment: I don't think the batch size is the issue. I've tried with a batch of 30 images and the session crashed in the same pattern.

Comment: @AngelinaMkrtchyan you can try to allocate `batch_images = np.zeros(...)` outside the while loop in you generator. If you create batch of 150 images with size 3518x2800 on the second step batch_1 + batch_2 will take about 33Gb of memory. If you will allocate it only once it should became constant (if we will put possible coping inside the model.fit() out of brackets).